# NLog asp.net core sends email automatically on error without logging it

Tags: email, logging, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

This is a weird situation, NLog users usually contact when NLog does not send emails but I am contacting you because NLog is sending emails.

I configured NLog using `UseNLog()`. I have nlog.config file. Thats it. Nothing else is set to configure it.

Nlog.config file just have target set to email me.

I do not even inject Logger in any OData controller.
It is a Asp.net Core project.

I am manually throwing exception from one of my controller. And it sends me email.
I am not even calling `Logger.LogError()`.

How is this happening?

Comment: We could better answer your question if you share the error message (in the email) and the nlog.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog integrates with ASP.NET Core logging. That isn't only a logger abstraction, but also ASP.NET Core is writing logs to that abstraction (debug info, http calls, errors etc).

So if ASP.NET Core catches an exception, it will write to the logging abstraction and NLog is configured to process the logging with UseNLog and the nlog.config.

This will be probably more clear if you [set-up the internal log of NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging), it shows the internals.

See also the [getting started with NLog and ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2), in the example below you will see some output examples.

Comment: is there a way we can control this and log when we need to log?

Comment: of course! In the nlog.config you could filter out the logs from microsoft, e.g the first rule could be: `<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />` (log to none). See https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2